# Как эффективно выбрать строки и пометить каждую, как прочитанную

Tags: sql, select, update

Здравствуйте,
есть простая задачка, сделать выборку строк из таблицы и пометить каждую выбранную строку флагом true ("просмотрено"). Причём поля выбранных строк мне нужно прочитать, а флаг нужно ставить, чтобы следующий раз не натыкаться на обработанные строки.
Я думаю такая задача часто встречается на практике, хотелось бы узнать, как поступают в таком случае. Думаю что есть лучшее решение чем просто выбрать строки, а потом каждой строке, в цикле, делать UPDATE SET viewed=true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например в Postgresql, можно это сделать так:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
   SET viewed=true 
WHERE viewed<>true
RETURNING *
```

Comment: Спасибо, это как раз то что искал.
Интересно, а есть ли в других БД подобный запрос с возвратом изменённых строк, или это только фишка PostgreSQL

Comment: OUTPUT в MSSQL. В других не знаю.